# Trigger Jenkins job when the content of specific file merged in gerrit repo

Tags: jenkins

I am looking to create a Jenkins pipeline job that triggers when the content of the file filename.json changes merged in the Gerrit repository's master branch.

```
.
├── Readme
├── tools-
└── src
    └── main
        ├── com
        │   └── xx
        ├── A
        │   ├── B
        │   ├── C
        │   ├── xx.conf
        │   ├── yy.conf
        │   ├── filename.json
        │   ├── cc
        │   └── dd.conf
        ├── dddd
        │   └── dd.yml
        └── gee
    enter code here
```

Can someone help with right Jenkins pipeline configuration instructions to trigger and perform necessary CI steps for that specific file trigger.

Environment: src code in gerrit 3.7 Jenkins version: 2.38

I tried to use Gerrit trigger event in Jenkins configuration.. looks like missing the correct Dynamic trigger settings and check merged settings.